# Java Convert Unknown Primitive Array to Object Array

Tags: java, xml, generics, serialization, reflection

I have been trying to create my own library to serialize and de-serialize primitive types from a class to xml and from xml to a class instance using reflection to examine method naming patterns and method return types.

So far I have been able to do this with all the basic primitive types but I got stuck on serializing an array of the same primitives.

For example I invoke the class method to get the array of primitives:

```
method.invoke(clazz, (Object[])null);
```

This method will return only a primitive array `int[], double[], float[], char[]` etc. though we don't know which one it will be.

I have tried using a generic such as

```
T t = (T)method.invoke(clazz, (Object[])null);
T[] t = (T[])method.invoke(clazz, (Object[])null);
```

But it doesn't let me cast from the primitive array to an object.

And you can't use `Array.newInstance` assuming we don't know the type.

Is there a way that I can convert this array of primitives to say an Object array in a generic manner.

In a generic manner meaning without needing to know or checking what the type of the array is. Or should I just cycle through all the primitive types and handle all of them separately.

I can do this both ways the only reason I want to do this in a generic manner is to cut down on the redundant code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) utility class

```
public static Object[] toObjectArray(Object array) {
    int length = Array.getLength(array);
    Object[] ret = new Object[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        ret[i] = Array.get(array, i);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I never thought that I could access the object as an array. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does  [java.lang.reflect.Array.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get%28java.lang.Object,%20int%29) do what you want?

Comment: You also need the getLength()

Comment: It would be my next step. This would allow me to get an item from the array but I still need to know how to store it in a proper array first.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object result = method.invoke(clazz, (Object[])null);
Class<?> arrayKlazz = result.getClass();
if (arrayKlazz.isArray()) {
    Class<?> klazz = result.getComponentType();
    if (klazz == int.class) {
        int[] intArray = arrayKlazz.cast(result);
    }
}
```

It seems more appropiate to hold (primitive) arrays in an Object (`result` above).

Comment: How will this help get an `Object[]` from the result?

Comment: `Object[]` is already answered. But solving the problem of serialization with `Object[]` for an `int[]`, `double[]` etcetera seems a bit going too far. **A general array should be held in an Object**. I want to suggest that without too large emphasis. If an `Object[]` is wished - fine.